# ActiveRecord callback on column change

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have the following relationship model:

```
class Doctor
  has_many :appointmets
  # has attribute 'average_rating' (float)
end

class Appointment
  belongs_to :doctor
  # has_attribute 'rating' integer
end
```

I want to set a callback to set `doctor.average_rating` each time an appointment gets rated, i.e. each time `rating` column on Appointments table gets touched.

I tried with this:

```
class Appointment
  after_update :update_dentist_average_rating, if: :rating_changed?
  # also tried with after_save 
private

  def update_dentist_average_rating
    ratings = Appointment.where(dentist_id: dentist.id).map(&:rating)
    doctor.average_rating = ratings.reduce(:+) / ratings.size if ratings.any?
    doctor.save
  end
end
```

But doesn't work, `appointment.dentist.average_rating` returns `nil` always. I can't seem to test whether the callback is running on `appointment.save`. **What I'm missing?**

**Edit:** this is the app flow

1. A user(of class Patient) saves an appointment with rating: nil and some doctor_id.
2. If the appointment.date is past, appointment.rating can be edited or set on a form via ''
3. Then I need to update appointment.doctor.average_rating

Comment: are you saving the changes on the doctor instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Achieved it with this callback, though I don't know if it's the best way:

```
after_save if: :rating_changed? do |apt|
  ratings = Appointment.where(doctor_id: 10).map(&:rating)
  doctor.average_rating = ratings.reduce(:+) / ratings.size if ratings.any?
  doctor.save!
end
```